# HTML - Chrome hides this image and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Ok so I did something as simple as adding

```
<img src="pomegrenate.jpg"  style="width: 700px;" />
```

to the op of a page on the website.

This is where it is so you can take a look for yourself: http://www.healthylivingmagazine.us/static/MEDIAKIT/banner_ads/

But in Chrome, it doesn't show the image. When I inspect it, I see that Chrome adds the following css and attributes to the image:

```
<img src="pomegrenate.jpg" style="width: 700px; display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px;" width="0" height="0">
```

However, even when I manually delete all the added styles and attributes, it still shows the image as 1x1 pixels according to chrome.

I've tested and this behavior occurs in Chromium running on Ubuntu 14.04, and Chrome on Windows 8.1.

Firefox and IE10 behave as expected.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using [adblocker](https://adblockplus.org/) on chrome?

Comment: Goddamnit. Nice call on that. What would make adblocker block that though? Should I change the image name?

Comment: @Nikzilla Because it's an ad.  Anyone else find it funny that the page where they proudly announce their product is Adblock Plus proof isn't actually Adblock Plus proof?

Comment: @gnack How is it an add? It doesn't even have an <a> tag around it. It's simply an image that I was asked to add.

Comment: @Nikzilla the page itself is an ad. The URL of the image is http://www.healthylivingmagazine.us/static/MEDIAKIT/banner_ads/pomegrenate.jpg, so AdBlock detects the "ad-like" URL and blocks it.

Comment: oooh that makes sense. Heh. The page is about ads not an ad though.

Comment: @Nikzilla oh, gotcha.  Well anyway that would be the reason.  You should also mention to whoever's responsible for the content that there's no such thing as "AdBlock Plus proof" so they might wanna double check that claim before someone complains.  (I was able to AdBlock the banner ad on that page with no problems, for instance).

Comment: @gnack Fully aware there is no such thing, but if management CAN put it there, they WILL put it there.

Comment: @Nikzilla It's because of the URL `/banner_ads/*` look at this image - http://oi62.tinypic.com/2qjljsh.jpg